# are setup() attributes supposed to be available?

Tags: setuptools, setup.py, python-packaging

I want to set attribute `my_package.version` for users to use, but can't make it work.

```
# file structure
my_package
├── src
│   └──my_package
├── VERSION
└── setup.py

# in VERSION file
0.0.1

# in setup.py file
import re
from setuptools import setup

VERSION_RE = re.compile(r"""([0-9dev.]+)""")


def get_version():
    with open("VERSION", "r") as fh:
        init = fh.read().strip()
    return VERSION_RE.search(init).group(1)


setup(
    author="ABC",
    version=get_version(),
    ...
)
```

but

```
>>> import my_package
>>> my_package.version  # expect '0.0.1' 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'my_package' has no attribute 'version'
```

Can anyone tell if I have the wrong expectation (that `my_package` should have attributes `author, version,...`)?

Or if the expectation is right then what is wrong? If so, what to fix here to set `my_package.version` for users to use?

Thanks

Comment: Also, you can check `dir(my_package)` to see the available options.

Comment: Those attributes are not automagically available. They need to be set explicitly in the Python code (for example in `src/my_package/__init__.py`). You probably need to show the content of `src/my_package/__init__.py` at least, for us to help you. -- This is how I do it (used to): https://sinoroc.gitlab.io/kb/python/project_version.html -- Side note: You can use [`setup.cfg`](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/declarative_config.html) instead of `setup.py` (or a mix of both). In `setup.cfg` it is as easy as `version = file: VERSION`.

Comment: @sinoroc glad to know they are not automagically available, when I had expected them to be.
 Nothing in `src/my_package/__init__.py`, but once
```
import importlib.metadata

_ version _ = importlib.metadata.version("my_package")
# or
version = importlib.metadata.version("my_package")
```
is added as in your post then it works (nice post, with clear problem part and solution part). Side note 1: yes, I am aware of `setup.cfg()`. Sidenote 2:  I am curious how to make `my_package.author` available as well. `importlib.metadata` seems to only have `version()`. Anyway, thanks for the answer.

Comment: Even if there is no dedicated shortcut property, the "author" should be in the "[_distribution metadata_](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.metadata.html#distribution-metadata)". Maybe something like `import importlib.metadata; author = importlib.metadata.metadata('general')['author']`.